# Getting a Triple Join To Work When Rows Are Missing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables. 1 table is like the master table and I want all rows from this table where GameID = X. Then I have a guides table which will have a matching ID and finally i have a user table that defines whether the user has selected this row to be hidden. this is causing issues. This table may not have a row associated with it. This table is shared amongst ALL users. The primary key of this table is UserID+InfoID. The query below returns what I want provided there are no other rows in the table for other userIDs.

```
SELECT PS_Info.*, PS_Guides.Guide, PS_Userhidden.* FROM PS_Info 
LEFT JOIN PS_Guides ON PS_Info.ID = PS_Guides.InfoID 
LEFT JOIN PS_Userhidden ON PS_Info.ID = PS_Userhidden.InfoID 
WHERE PS_Info.GameID = :ID AND (PS_Userhidden.UserID = :UserID) 
OR (PS_Userhidden.UserID IS NULL AND PS_Userhidden.InfoID IS NULL)
```

So I will run the php script and have infoID =1 and userID=1. In the table there is infoID=1 and userid = 2, but nothing will be returned for this row. If I remove `PS_Userhidden.UserID = :UserID` I get multiple of the same row. The user table will grow to millions of rows. I need a way to make this query stick to the primary key of the users table so it will still return a row if no match exists in the user table and also return a row if there is a match in the users table for the specific user

Comment: Does that last AND correspond to your OR?? You should wrap them in parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to move the condition on the hidden user to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT i.*, g.Guide, h.*
FROM PS_Info i LEFT JOIN
     PS_Guides g
     ON i.ID = g.InfoID LEFT JOIN
     PS_Userhidden h 
     ON i.ID = h.InfoID AND h.UserID = :UserID
WHERE i.GameID = :ID ;
```

Your description of the problem sounds like something that can happen when you start fiddling with conditions in the `WHERE` clause of a `LEFT JOIN`.  It is a little hard to follow though.  If this doesn't work, edit your question with sample data and desired results -- or, better yet, set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: That worked. I didn't know I could put extra conditions on the join like this. This is definitely a valuable one for me. Thank you so much for the help